# Carriage Return/Line Break Nodes in Inkscape XML Editor

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, svg

I recently exported an AI file as an SVG and there are a ton of "carriage return/line breaks" as nodes in the XML editor.  Opening other SVGs does not reproduce this issue.

Is this a UTF issue? AI exporting issue?  Is there a programmatic way to remove these?

Not a huge issue, I can simply remove them, but does anyone have any insight on why this is occurring?

If I open a text editor and remove the line break between `<g></g>` tags, the line break node is gone after reloading.  Seems odd considering I have other SVG files with line breaks in them and those are not nodes in the XML editor for Inkscape.

Inkscape 1.0.1

Thanks!

[image: XML Line Break Nodes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is related to [Inkscape Issue #1138: *(XML editor dialog) Hide whitespace nodes outside of text elements even when xml:space="preserve" is in root node*](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/1138)

There are two ways I was able to fix this for myself. Hope this works for you as well!

**Inkscape Method**

1. Open up the XML Editor
2. Click on the topmost `svg:svg` element
3. In the attributes panel, delete the `xml:space` attribute
4. Save your project
5. Either revert your project or close and reopen Inkscape

**Text Editor Method**

1. Take a look toward the top of the file (usually the 3rd or 4th line) for the main `<svg>` tag
2. Find the attribute `xml:space="preserve"` and erase
3. Save the file and open it back up in Inkscape